# How do I run shell script from Android application

Tags: android

I know that I can run an Android instrumentation using abd shell. But I want to run the instrumentation from another Android app.

Basically, I want to create an Android app that tests another Android app using instrumentation.

Please let me know if there is a better way to create an Android app that can access to the another Android app to run some test codes..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run instrumentation from code using [startInstrumentation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startInstrumentation%28android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29), like this

```
startInstrumentation(componentName, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the source code as well. Appreciate it:)